# Idea C++ auto unity build system, would it work?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, compiler-construction

So this may sound a bit crazy but i had the following idea...

In c++ they call a unity build when you put all your code in one file using #include's or simply copy and pasting.  This allows for lightning fast compilation.

Now for simplicity lets assume we have a header only library and we restrict ourselves to only using classes (that way we have a garaunteed namespace).
Now i was wondering how well this would work if made automatic. A script/tool would be made to preprocess the .h files; picking out includes and dependencies. The tool would walk every .h file recursively and construct a mapping of dependencies of includes. It would then place these dependencies in one file (main.cpp) using #includes and compile.

Now i want to get your guy's opinions on this idea of automatic unity build creator.  Is this smart to do? Would it work as I expect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity builds are overprized, really.

> This allows for lightning fast compilation.

This is not quite true these days. Compilation is not I/O bound assuming you have dedicated machine for compilation with enough RAM. Every modern operating system caches files after first read and than get them from memory. You can avoid intermediate files by piping or storing them in RAM drive. So preprocessor work is just concatenating files in most of the time. This is fast. Real time is spent in compilation and linking.

So any serious application having thousands of files will be huge. Real world example - we work with app where source code takes more than 100MB of data (without system and 3rd party includes). So your system would have  to operate on approximate 150MB file. I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers would refuse to compile it. Not to mention time to compile. It is way better to split into smaller files and compile in parallel. Again real example - single thread compile took 40 minutes to finish, running on one server with 16 threads around 2.5-3 minutes and compiling on farm of 16 servers each 16 core with distcc 30 seconds plus some time to link.

The other benefit of unity builds which is better optimization vanishes when LTO and static build are done.

Answering your question - yes you can do that. Does it make sense? Doubtful.

Comment: How long would a unity build take on a 150 MB file. I've heard stories where builds took an entire day because of the code base. When combining it all in one file it took minutes.

Comment: I can't speak for other builds - I can for things I know. Additionally - how much memory would it take? For given example using LTO alone took around 35GB of RAM - and it was after it was improved in gcc 5.1 or 5.4 - before that it crashed.

Comment: Not I/O bound, yes. However, `clang -ftime-report` shows that in our project 90% of the compile time is spend parsing headers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you accomplish?

You hate "header only" because  you" need to recompile the world every time". In your "brave new world" there is only 1 file so it is always going to be compiled every time - no matter what.

People have spent a lot of time and effort making C++ such that it can use libraries etc to help speed up compilation. Oh, by the way the system I'm looking at today has 17 million + lines of code. You want that in one file?

Links provided by OP in the comments are a good explanation. The big problem I see is scalability. It did remind me of one area in my (inherited) code base where the guards are outside the includes to avoid opening files. e.g.

```
#ifndef BLAH_H
#include <blah.h>
#endif
```

Comment: yes.. why not, if it can fit into ram and gcc accepts it.. Would it compile faster than what your doing now?

Comment: No, it would be heaps slower. Now I recompile the 1000 lines of of code in the file that changed not the 17 million lines in the whole system.

Comment: But what happens when you have to release. You need to spent a week recompiling or heavily invest in new hardware?

Comment: A week compiling? Where are you pulling that from? A full clean build of my 17 million + system (the smaller of the 2 I'm looking after) takes a couple of hours - and it could probably be less but the makefile is a old and dodgy. You seem to be ignoring the basic flaw in your whole idea which is you ALWAYS recompile EVERYTHING every time you build. How can recompile everything all the time ever be better than recompile just what has changed? How do you think your release build can possibly be faster than mine?

Comment: Like I said.. some people claim they have reduced their build times by 90%.  So lets say it takes you 60 * 3 = 180 minutes to build your project.  The same unity build would take only 18 mins. For a project that size, you obviously would not develop with a unity build. But creating a unity build for release would save massive amounts of time. 
But for smaller projects like 10k lines that take 30 seconds , would only take 3 seconds during unity build.  Also Subtract that for the time you have to deal with header + cpp files throughout the project.

Comment: What im getting at is a fairly small 10k project would be ok to recompile via unity build.. Easier to refactor code. No worrying about header depends. No worrying about linking issues. Managing half as many files just takes a load off your work flow.

Comment: I just don't see how any of your claims hold water. Perhaps you could provide some links? I'm happy to learn something new and admit where I'm wrong, but in this case, I'm confident that no "real" C++ engineer would even think about doing as you suggest.

Comment: Maybe these links will explain better than me:
http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/
and
https://cheind.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/reducing-compilation-time-unity-builds/

The entire premise is that the compiler does much less work during a unity build. It doesnt have to link, doesnt have to open as many files, doesnt have to parse as many files, etc.